# Input of characters into RichTextBox too slow, how make more fast?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

When I enter text using the keyboard, I see that the conclusion of characters in the editor window, a little behind the keystrokes, it do inconvenience in my work, how make that characters appear simultaneously with pressing keys.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if you have any ICommands in that view with complicated CanExecute code. Everytime a property changes (and a lot of property changes in a RichTextBox) these ICommands will check if they are still able to execute - and if the logic is heavy - you'll pay in terms of performance.

Try to see if you can reproduce it in a Window with nothing but a RichTextBox - if it still slow - check to see if you have upgraded your video-drivers, Direct-X or have anything using all your system resources.

Last, but not least - see if you can reproduce on a friends computer or another computer - input in RichTextBox should be near instantaneous.

Comment: I have the same problem... it is very annoying. Actually it is small lag between key pressing and rendering a letter, it is about 100..150 ms. But it makes user feel uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn down the application frame rate to around 5 it seems to make the input very fast.... but all your animations look like potato.